# Jquery ajaxStart срабатывает столько сколько она была вызвана

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Есть форма отправки фото - [image: введите сюда описание изображения] .

При отправки фото через `ajax` (внутри функции `on.change`), срабатывает функция `ajaxStart`, внутри которого происходит вставка блока с анимацией загрузки. Но после первой загрузки, когда я хочу загрузить фото на другой блок, анимация загрузки срабатывает в местах где я уже добавлял фото, а мне надо именно в том блоке в которой я загружаю фото.

Вот код:

```
$(add_product_form.photoUpload_field.field).on("input", function(e, elem) {
    var input_id = $(e.currentTarget).attr('id');
    var container = '.block_slctd_photo.cTtfa label[for=' + input_id + '] .laUhuq';
    UploadPhoto(this, this, container, Types.imgType, '/fileupload/upload_productPhoto');

})


function UploadPhoto(id, indicator, container, types, url) {
    var filetype = id.files[0].type;
    var files = id.files;
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    var data = new FormData();
    $.each(files, function(key, value) {
        data.append(key, value);
    });

    $(document).ajaxStart(function(e) {
        $(container).html(load_icon.html);
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(data) {
            data = JSON.parse(data);
            $(container).html('<img src = "' + data.file_path + data.file_name + '"/>');
            prod_images.push(data);
        },
        error: function(data) {
            console.log("er");
        },
    });
}
```

То есть функция:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function(e) {
    $(container).html(load_icon.html);
});
```

Срабатывает в блоках с загруженными фото, а мне нужно в выбранном блока

Вот `html` код:

```
<div class="block_slctd_photo cTtfa">
    <label for="upload_photo-4">
        <div class="laUhuq">
            <i class="fas fa-camera"></i>
            <span>Добавить</span>
        </div>
    </label>
</div>
<div class="block_slctd_photo cTtfa">
    <label for="upload_photo-5">
        <div class="laUhuq">
            <i class="fas fa-camera"></i>
            <span>Добавить</span>
        </div>
    </label>
</div>
<div class="block_slctd_photo cTtfa">
    <label for="upload_photo-6">
        <div class="laUhuq">
            <i class="fas fa-camera"></i>
            <span>Добавить</span>
        </div>
    </label>
</div>
<div class="x4NlIZ">
    <input style="display: none;" type="file" id="upload_photo-1">
    <input style="display: none;" type="file" id="upload_photo-2">
    <input style="display: none;" type="file" id="upload_photo-3">
</div>
```

Comment: А зачем, собственно, вешать событие `ajaxStart` каждый раз при вызове `UploadPhoto()` ? Почему не написать просто `$(container).html(load_icon.html)` ?